# invertible linear transformation $H\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ exists such that $H(u)=T(u)$ for all $u\in U$ iff $null(T)\cap U =$ {$0$}

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose U$\subset$V is an $T$-invariant subspace and $V$ is finite dimensional. Prove that an invertible linear transformation $H\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ exists such that $H(u)=T(u)$ for all $u\in U$ iff $null(T)\cap U =$ {$0$}

---

My attempt:

To prove the forward direction I think I have to define a basis for $U$ and then extend it to a basis of $V$.

I also know that since this is $T$-invariant, For $u \in U$, $T(u) \in U$

Then I can say $H(u)=T(u)$

I am a little confused on how to piece this all together

Answer (score 1):

Suppose first that $H$ exists. If $x\in\text{null}(T)\cap U$, then $Hx=Tx=0$. As $H$ is invertible, $x=0$. Thus $\text{null}(T)\cap U=\{0\}$.

Conversely, assume that  $\text{null}(T)\cap U=\{0\}$. This means that, restricted to $U$, the operator $T$ is one-to-one. As $U$ is $T$ invariant, $TU\subset U$ and it has the same dimension as $U$ (from $T$ being one-to-one) so $TU=U$. That, the restriction of $T$ to $U$ is a bijection $U\to U$. Let $W$ be a complement of $U$ (i.e., a subspace such that $U\oplus W=V$). This always exists by simply completing a basis of $U$ to a basis of $V$.

Now define $H$ by $H(x+y)=Tx+y$ for $x\in U$, $y\in W$.

Comment: Can you explain why T is 1-1?

Comment: On $U$; because $\text{null}(T)\cap U=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks! and how does that imply that $Hx=Tx$?

Comment: Not sure what you want to see. The whole point is to define $H$ so that $Hx=Tx$ when $x\in U$.